# Run Angular application without a library from a linked module

Tags: angular

I'm trying to run an angular module, which links another module that has 2 libraries (@ angular / flex-layout, @ swimlane / ngx-datatable). The problem is that in the module I want to run I don't need these 2 libraries, so I didn't import them. So I get this error:

```
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/flex-layout' in 'C:\Users\Mihai BONDRILA\Documents\Projects\BERC-WORKSPACE\portal\mobile-client\node_modules\berc-service\fesm2015'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/berc-service/fesm2015/berc-service.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@swimlane/ngx-datatable' in 'C:\Users\Mihai BONDRILA\Documents\Projects\BERC-WORKSPACE\portal\mobile-client\node_modules\berc-service\fesm2015'
```

Is there any way to make it run without importing in the 2 libraries?

Comment: is @angular/flex-layout and @swimlane/ngx-datatable actually installed?

Comment: It depends on whether those dependencies(@ angular / flex-layout, @ swimlane / ngx-datatable) are peerDependencies or under dependencies block. In case they're under dependencies you would have to have them installed under node_modules so that the library is enabled to work perfectly.